# How to get Bash's revert-line in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, key-bindings

*Since macOS changed to `zsh` as default, I try to update my keybindings for it.*

In `bash` I could use the following command:

```
bind '"\C-a": revert-line' # Revert/resets the changed history line while you are on it with the the cursor
```

I do not find any function like that on [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets).

```
bindkey "^a" what-to-put-here
```

Do you know how to accomplish it with `zsh`?

Answer (score 3):

`revert-line` is a function provided by `readline`. While, ZSH doesn't depend on `readline`. ZSH has its own editor in command line called ZLE(ZSH Line Editor).

There doesn't seem to be a reset all function in the ZLE builtins. Correct me if I'm wrong.

`undo` may be an alternative for you.

> undo
>
> Incrementally undo the last text modification. When called from a user-defined widget, takes an optional argument indicating a previous state of the undo history as returned by the UNDO_CHANGE_NO variable; modifications are undone until that state is reached, subject to any limit imposed by the UNDO_LIMIT_NO variable.

```sh
bindkey "^a" undo
```

Comment: `undo` doesn't undo all the changes at once like `revert-line` does in bash, so you have to invoke it multiple times, but it's sure as heck better than nothing